# difference between the LM1117-5 IC packages

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm using LM1117-5 as a voltage regulator. In the datasheet of it they have mentioned different packages like LM1117DT-5.0/NOPB,LM1117DTX-5.0/NOPB,LM1117IDT-5.0/NOPB, LM1117IDTX-5.0/NOPB , LM1117IMP-5.0/NOPB. what are the differences between this packages ( DT, DTX, IDT, IDTX, IMP, MP etc. ) and which one is suitable in which applications. ?

Comment: data sheet link for the lazy is needed!

Comment: and for the lazy http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117-n.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a large table covering package codes at the end of the datasheet.

From a quick glance, it appears that "DT" parts are TO-252 and "MP" are SOT-223.  The "X" indicates the parts are supplied on tape-and-reel with 2500 parts per reel.  Non-"X" parts are supplied in plastic rails containing 75 parts.  The "I" indicates industrial temperature range.

I leave further decoding to the student.

Comment: and if they did not already guess, NOPB means "No Pb", or "No Lead" as in, the metallic element "lead", which is Pb on the table of elements.